# undefine en nodejs al crear carpeta

Tags: nodejs, filewriter, mkdir

De la base de datos estoy obteniendo `ip` y `id`, y al momento de querer crear una carpeta y ponerle el `ip` como nombre me sale undefined y la carpeta se crea pero con el nombre undefined, adentro de esa carpeta estoy creando una foto y el `id` es el nombre que le coloco y el archivo si se crea bien, pero la carpeta no coloca el nombre de `ip`.

Mi codigo:

```
var dir = `cr.${ip}`;
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    require("fs").writeFile(`${dir}/${_id}.jpg`, binaryData, "binary", err =>
      console.log(err)
    )
  } catch(err) {
    if(err.code == 'EEXIST') {
      require("fs").writeFile(`${dir}/${_id}.jpg`, binaryData, "binary", err =>
        console.log(err)
      )
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Seguramente es porque "ip" es nulo. Si después de var dir = `cr.${ip}`; agregas console.log(dir), ¿Te imprime el valor esperado?

Comment: Creo que estás diciendo que su `catch(err)` retorna `undefined` eso? Has resuelto el problema? 0.o